# Checking for user authentication error codes with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In older versions of Swift, the following code could be used to check for user auth errors:

```
 if (error != nil) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch (errorCode) {
        case .UserDoesNotExist:
            println("Handle invalid user")
        case .InvalidEmail:
            println("Handle invalid email")
        case .InvalidPassword:
            println("Handle invalid password")
        default:
            println("Handle default situation")
        }
    }
}
```

`FAuthenticationError` doesn't seem to exist anymore, and the documentation makes it look like it's been replaced with `FIRAuthErrorNameKey`.

Putting `FIRAuthErrorNameKey` in where `FauthenticationError` is results in the error:

```
cannot call nonfunctiontype String
```

Here's the documentation I'm looking at : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Any ideas how to achieve what was done with the first block of code in Swift 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `FIRAuthErrorCode` - it is an int enum

> enum      FIRAuthErrorCode {    FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidCustomToken =
>   17000, FIRAuthErrorCodeCustomTokenMismatch = 17002,
>   FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidCredential = 17004,
>   FIRAuthErrorCodeUserDisabled = 17005,

From here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth_errors

Try to use like this:

```
if (error != nil) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?._code)!) {
                switch errCode {
                case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                ...
                case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
                ...
                case .errorCodeWrongPassword:
                    }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 3**

Thanks to TonyMkenu for the direction. In my project which was recently converted to Swift 3, using the FIRAuthErrorCode asks me to use a default:

```
if (error != nil) {
     // an error occurred while attempting login
     if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?._code)!) {
               switch errCode {
                    case .errorCodeRequiresRecentLogin:
                       print("There was an error")
                    default:
                       print("Handle default situation")
                    }
                }
}else {
    // no error occurred
    print("Success")
}
```